# Adding Key-Value pair to a Series that does not have a given Key (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, list, series

I want to update a series if it is missing a key, but my code is generating an error.

This is my code:

```
for item in list:
    if item not in my_series.keys():
        my_series = my_series[item] = 0
```

Where my_series is a series of dtype int64. It's actually a value count.

My code above is generating the following error

```
'int' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Just write my_series[item] = 0. That said, I'm curious as to the error; could someone explain it? I imagine the multi-assignment first does a=0, then tries to implement a[item], so 0[item], but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "series"? There's no such data type in python if I'm not mistaken. You seem to use it as it was a dict. Do you need to set default value to 0 for a key "item"?
If so:

```
for item in <definitely_list_is_a_bad_name>:
    my_series[item] = my_series.get(item) if my_series.get(item, None) is not None else 0
```

Comment: I mean the type that is on this page.  I realized just now that I forgot to include "pandas" in the question description but I thought contextually it made sense.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html

Answer (score 0):

From what I read in the docs, a Pandas series functions much like a dict, so my comment remains valid:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
my_series = pd.Series(data=d, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
my_list = ['a','h','c','d']

for item in my_list:
    if item not in my_series:
        my_series[item] = 0
        
print(my_series)

# a    1
# b    2
# c    3
# h    0
# d    0
# dtype: int64
```

Btw, as John Doe mentioned, "list" is a bad choice of a name; don't use Python keywords as objects names, else you will overwrite those keywords and risk problems later.